# PHP - Do an else to many ifs?

Tags: php, request, if-statement

**EDIT:** Very simple, figure it out. Just put an else{} without a } before and that will work for both ifs.

Well I wrote this code and it works ok

```
  if($_REQUEST['pag']){

        // Variável da página
        $pag = $_REQUEST['pag'];

        // Possíveis páginas
        if($pag == "registrar"){
        include "inc/register.php";
        }
        if ($pag == "recuperar"){
        include "inc/recover.php";
        }

}
```

But what if the user types `?pag=ofksaofkoasdkfkopsd` ?

The page won't exist, so I want to include a file if that happens.
Is there a way to make this without using a list or something?

Answer (score 3):

you can do this by [**`switch`**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) and that would be better way then if because

> The switch statement is similar to a series of IF statements on the same expression. In many occasions, you may want to compare the same variable (or expression) with many different values, and execute a different piece of code depending on which value it equals to. This is exactly what the switch statement is for. ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) )

```
switch($_REQUEST['pag']){

case "registrar":
   include "inc/register.php";
   break;

case :"recuperar":
  include "inc/recover.php";
  break;

default:
  //default you want to include
  break;


}
```

i hope you know about the complexity of the code and in your case switch case has less complexity in worst/average  case

Comment: Such big code.. I figure it out using 1 statement. Check the edited question again.

Comment: This is the better way to do it, using `switch`

Answer (score 2):

Try with `if` with `else` like

```
$pag = $_REQUEST['pag'];

// Possíveis páginas
if($pag == "registrar"){
    include "inc/register.php";
}
elseif ($pag == "recuperar"){
    include "inc/recover.php";
}
else{
    include "inc/default.php"
}
```

Or you can use switch case where you can found default option like

```
switch($pag)
{
   case "register":include "inc/register.php";
                   break;
   case "recuperar":include "inc/recover.php";
                   break;
   default : include "inc/default.php";
}
```

Comment: No need for a break in the last "case/default", especially if it's default :)

Comment: Thanku @Virus721.I just gave ans fastly...Thanku for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

use `if {} else{}` or `switch` case.

You can use `nested if else` though.

At least give an eye on the docs - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to use an array? That really would be the best way to go IMHO. Adding pages is easier, you get less duplicated code... It would also be trivial to load the array from a config file or DB instead of having it hard-coded in a later stadium. I see only benefits.

```
$pages = array( "registrar" => "inc/register.php",
                "recuperar" => "inc/recover.php" );

$requestedPage = $_REQUEST["pag"];

if(array_key_exists($requestedPage, $pages)){
    include $pages[$requestedPage];
}
else {
    include "inc/error404.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

some Use the switch command.

```
switch ($_REQUEST['pag']) {
    case 'registrar':
        echo "some text or action";
        break;
    case 'xxx':
        echo "some text or action";
        break;
    case 'xxxx':
        echo "some text";
        break;
    default:
       echo "some text";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $pag = isset($_REQUEST['pag']) ? $_REQUEST['pag'] : null;

        switch($pag) {
        case 'registrar':
            require 'inc/register.php';
            break;        
        case 'recuperar':
            require "inc/recover.php";
            break;
        default:
            // Include your default page
        }
```

In a non-dynamic language like C++ you'll have to use
if() elseif() else to compare non-constant values.

Comment: You should leave your question as it is. An answer is useless when you don't have the question it answers. And try not to pick the most unefficient solution ;-)

Comment: Well, I went trying to use your code, because I like to know different options.. It gives me an unexpected ) in the swith() line.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($condition1) 
{
  //code
} 
elseif ($condition2)
{
  //code
}
elseif ($condition3)
{
  //code
}
...
else 
{
  //this is what happens when no other condition is true
}
```

switch is a better practice. check @user1752647's answer

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `elseif` and `else`

```
if($pag == "registrar"){
    include "inc/register.php";
}elseif($pag == "recuperar"){
    include "inc/recover.php";
}else{
    ... //include a file if the page doesn't exist
}
```

Or you can do it with a switch

```
switch($pag){
    case "registrar":
        include "inc/register.php";
        break;
    case "recuperar":
        include "inc/recover.php";
        break;
    default:
        ... //include a file if the page doesn't exist 
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use this code

```
$pages = array("register", "recover");
if (in_array($_REQUEST["pag"], $pages)) {
include $_REQUEST["pag"].".php";
}
else{
include "default.php";
}
```